# Упростить код php

Tags: php, циклы

Есть такой массив

```
$names = array('aHeight', 'aWidth', 'aLength', 'aMaterial', 'aModel', 'aColor', 'aWeight', 'aThickness', 'aQntShelv', 'aType', 'aSeries', 'aBrand');
```

И такой

```
$json_data = array (
      'sd_cat_id' => isset($sd_cat_id) ? $sd_cat_id : '',
      'param_array' =>  $this->request->post,
      'aHeight' => isset($aHeight) ? array_unique($aHeight) : '',
      'aWidth' => isset($aWidth) ? array_unique($aWidth) : '',
      'aLength' => isset($aLength) ? array_unique($aLength) : '',
      'aMaterial' => isset($aMaterial) ? array_unique($aMaterial) : '',
      'aModel' => isset($aModel) ? array_unique($aModel) : '',
      'aColor' => isset($aColor) ? array_unique($aColor) : '',
      'aWeight' => isset($aWeight) ? array_unique($aWeight) : '',
      'aThickness' => isset($aThickness) ? array_unique($aThickness) : '',
      'aType' => isset($aType) ? array_unique($aType) : '',
      'aSeries' => isset($aSeries) ? array_unique($aSeries) : '',
      'aBrand' => isset($aBrand) ? array_unique($aBrand) : '',
      'aQntShelv' => isset($aQntShelv) ? array_unique($aQntShelv) : ''
  );
```

Можно ли как-то упростить добавление параметров, что бы не прописывать вручную каждое значение, а через цикл например. Пробовал делать так

```
$json_data = array (
      'sd_cat_id' => isset($sd_cat_id) ? $sd_cat_id : '',
      'param_array' =>  $this->request->post
```

);

```
foreach($names as $name) {
    if(isset($$name)) {
        $json_data[$$name] = array_unique($$name);
    } else {
        $json_data[$$name] = '';
    }
```

Но выдает ошибку Illegal offset type
Как можно упростить данный код ?

Comment: а зачем брать переменную переменных? Ведь  `$json_data[$name]`

Comment: `$json_data[$name] = isset($$name) ? array_unique($$name) :[] ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужна [переменная переменной](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php) при обращении к массиву `$json_data` (`$json_data[$$name]`), т.к. `$name` *уже* содержит проверяемый ключ массива.

Так что как-то так:

```
foreach($names as $name) {
    if(isset($$name)) {
        $json_data[$name] = array_unique($$name);
    } else {
        $json_data[$name] = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: да я уже и сам допер)) но все равно спасибо)
И еще вопрос а правильно ли что я таким способом (через $$name) добавляю и создаю массивы. Просто данных с каждым разом все больше и много времени уходит на создание однотипных данных